# Why do I get Fsync failed error?

Tags: filesystems, root

I'm trying to follow [MongoDB documentation instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/#transparent-huge-pages-thp-settings) to configure LTH properly for a machine running MongoDB.

One of the instructions consists of creating a script which runs at boot. Unfortunately, neither the suggested script, nor the similar code [rewritten as a systemd service](https://askubuntu.com/a/820116/229568) work.

When debugging the issue, I encountered another one. When I execute:

```
root@demo:/# echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

the command appears to run successfully, but the file remain unchanged, so if I then run:

```
root@demo:/# cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

it returns the original content:

```
always madvise [never]
```

I tried to modify the file with `vim`; when trying to save the file, it complains that *Fsync failed*. While [this error has been documented](https://askubuntu.com/q/167819/229568), in my case, there is enough disk space on `/` (20% used, 7 GB available.)

I run the command in `sudo` mode, and the file permissions seem correct:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 ...
```

The `/sys` directory is not [mounted in read-only mode](http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Content/Note-About-%20Using-Transparent-Huge-Pages.htm#Diabling) either, as shown by:

```
root@demo:/# grep sysfs /proc/mounts
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sysfs`, the filesystem usually mounted on `/sys`, is a special virtual filesystem to interface with the Linux kernel.

The files in it aren't real files, they represent data structures in the kernel and only support rather simple access methods. Reading from such a file asks the kernel for information. Writing to such a file instructs the kernel to change a setting or perform an action.

That's why `vim` fails. It tries to access the virtual files in ways optimized for real files and this isn't supported on `sysfs`.

Your first command

```
root@demo:/# echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

was already successful!

Many sysfs "files", including `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`, don't only print the current setting when read, but print all possible modes and use brackets to describe which of multiple modes is active instead.

In your case `never` is in brackets, so the mode you tried to activate with `echo` is already active:

```
always madvise [never]
```

If you're interested in how `sysfs` works, you can read more about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) or in the [Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt).