# Why is /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed not modifiable by sudo emacs?

Tags: emacs, cpu-frequency, nano

I would like to edit `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed` to change its content from 800000 to  1600000.

1. I first try with emacs

   ```
   $ sudo emacs -nw /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
   ```

   In emacs I have changed the value to 1600000 in the file, and when I
   save the changes, the message buffer says:

   ```
   Saving file /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed...
   Wrote /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
   ```

   But after I exit emacs and read the file again, the value is still
   800000
2. Then I try another way

   ```
   $ sudo less /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
   ```

   wherein I hit `v` to invoke default editor which is nano, and then I
   change the value. After I exit nano and less, and check the file
   again, the file has been changed successfully.

I wonder why the first way doesn't work while the second does?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Thinkpad T400. Thanks.

Comment: Emacs doesn't complain anything about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get Fsync failed error?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351031/why-do-i-get-fsync-failed-error)

Comment: When Emacs saves a file, it renames the old file so that it becomes a backup file, and then creates a *new* file with the original name. I don't know what happened in your case, and why Emacs didn't complain, but Emacs is clearly the wrong tool for this.

Comment: @JohanMyréen what are the options for the right tools?

Comment: `echo 1600000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed`

Answer (score 3):

From the comments:

> When Emacs saves a file, it renames the old file so that it becomes a backup file, and then creates a new file with the original name. I don't know what happened in your case, and why Emacs didn't complain, but Emacs is clearly the wrong tool for this. – Johan Myréen

The right tool would be anything that just overwrites the original file (or even just appends to it), rather than trying to rename the old file.

Remember: nothing under `/sys` is a real, persistent file. They are all kernel parameters and status information, presented in the form of files. You should not be able to move, rename or delete them.

There used to be commands named `cpufreq-info` and `cpufreq-set` for manipulating these settings; in more recent releases, the commands may now (or soon) be `cpupower frequency-info` and `cpupower frequency-set` respectively.

Comment: cpufreq-info and cpufreq-set belong to `cpufrequtils`, Are you sure that  `cpufrequtils` is replaced with `cpupower`?

Comment: The upstream of the `cpufrequtils` package hasn't been updated since 2015, and the `cpupower` utility is included in the kernel source package, in the `tools/power` directory. Though it may not be quite replaced *yet*, it sure looks like it will be soon.

Comment: But why I can't find `cpupower` in synaptic package manager?

Comment: Your distribution is apparently not on the bleeding edge :-)

Comment: which distribution has cpupower?

Comment: More seriously, search for "linux-cpupower" package on Debian 9, or in jessie-backports.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the conventional method to set 1600 MHz speed is:

```
echo 1600000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
```

To verify it's effect use:

```
$ cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/
$ paste <(ls *) <(cat *) | column -s $'\t' -t
affected_cpus                             0
cpuinfo_max_freq                          3500000
cpuinfo_min_freq                          800000
cpuinfo_transition_latency                4294967295
energy_performance_available_preferences  default performance balance_performance balance_power power 
energy_performance_preference             balance_performance
related_cpus                              0
scaling_available_governors               performance powersave
scaling_cur_freq                          807325
scaling_driver                            intel_pstate
scaling_governor                          powersave
scaling_max_freq                          3500000
scaling_min_freq                          800000
scaling_setspeed                          <unsupported>
```

On my machine `scaling_setspeed` cannot be set as I have an i7-6700HQ. The same is true on my old 3rd generation i7-3630QM.

So on these platforms I would set `scaling_min_freq` and `scaling_max_freq` to the same level and `p_state` would never fluctuate. The same setting I would likely apply across all CPU's in `.../cpu0/...` through `.../cpu7/...`